SwiftUI Combine, is there a way to add an index or uuid befoe a send
var peripheralSubject: PassthroughSubject<CBPeripheral, Never> = .init()

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        peripheralSubject.send(peripheral)
    }

this code gives the - requires that AnyCancellable conform to randomaccesscollection error in the List
is there any way to add an id before the combine send

How is the above code related to List? (The solution is going to be to modify your List code, not this code.)

As far as I know, there is no such method, but this situation can be controlled with a new structure.
struct IdentifiedPeripheral: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    let peripheral: CBPeripheral
}

